Why does Chrome takes several seconds to "wake up" on an M4 MacBook Pro?
I use the current version of Google Chrome (131.0.6778.140) on macOS (15.1.1).
After switching to a M4 MacBook Pro (previous an old intel MacBook Pro) Chrome takes several seconds to "wake up" after I come back from lunch.
The beachball will appear periodically while it is waking up and then disappear leading me to believe it has recovered, but I still cannot click on anything in Chrome. Example: New tabs will not open.
Other applications are not stalled.
I have followed instructions to turn off memory saving features and it still does not help.
I bought a 48GB machine specifically so I would not need to conserve it.
Here are my settings:

What can I do to have Chrome immediately available when I wake my computer up?
Would Firefox have the same issue?

Does the same issue occur with other browsers, e.g., independent Firefox, or Chrome-based Brave browser?

@DrMoishePippik. IDK.  That will take some time to test so I will wait a day or two to try.
